# How to implement to add a #FEATURE(V1) #ENDFEATURE(V1) when changing a line in vim?

Tags: vim

I need this function with VIM:

In VIM, when changing one line, vim can automatically add two lines #DEL-LINE/#END-DEL-LINE to embrace this line, and add a new one #ADD-LINE/#END-ADD-LINE) to record the edit steps.

EDIT:
For example, a text file was opened with VIM, and there is a line like:

```
a = b;
```

when changing this line (move cursor at this line and type "c" or "i" or "d" "x" or something like this to edit this line), vim will add the line 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 (line 2 was original line)

```
1,    #DEL-LINE
2,    a = b;
3,    #END-DEL-LINE
4,
5,    #ADD-LINE
6,     
7,    #END-ADD-LINE
```

(and line numbers ont the left was just for reference, not really in file)

And the cursor will be put on the line 6, wating for input for changing.

If just add one line, will be:

```
#ADD-LINE
b = c;
#END-ADD-LINE
```

If there any existing plugin or configuration file that will do this?
Or any idea to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand your problem.. :( what is your input, and what is your output (expected)?

Comment: Input is: change the "a = b" in vim, and output is"#DEL-LINE
a = b;
#END-DEL-LINE
#ADD-LINE
b = a;
#END-ADD-LINE

Comment: @Kent, the output is line 1 - 7 in question.

Comment: It sound's like you want to reimplement diff? (and maybe patch). Why do you want vim to do this?

Comment: @ FDinoff, No, I'm not looking for a diff, though it looks like a result of diff. I just vim can add those lines in real time when changing a existin fiel.